# I don't want fancyheader to display runing header in bold font

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using the below code, which gives running headers in **bold** font.

But I want normal font.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,authblk,eurosym,fancyhdr,float,footmisc,graphics,graphicx,pdflscape,pslatex,rotating,setspace,subfig,tabularx,url,xargs} 
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames]{xcolor}  %

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{Header text}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{Tom \& Jerry}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\section{Introduction}
Your introduction goes here! Simply start writing your document and use the Recompile button to view the updated PDF preview. Examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.
\end{document}
```

But the running header shows in boldface. I just want it in normal font.

Comment: Don't use `\textbf` (bf = bold font).

Answer (score 0):

See John's answer:

```
\fancyhead[RO]{Header text}
\fancyhead[LE]{Tom \& Jerry}
```